# How to create a curve from a mesh?

Tags: mesh, path

I have a quite complex mesh object (a spaghetti like structure, see image [image: Protein Structure]).

What I need is a curve/path that does through the core of that structure.
Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Glmiqkxuw7MGCYJA4PSxLw1MF4X_Ntv0/view?usp=sharing

I would really appreciate any ideas on how to achieve that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, please share your file, it will help: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ... maybe you could select one edge loop all along the pipe, then convert it to curve?

Comment: Sure, I updated the post with a link to the file. That would actually be a good idea. I might have to remesh it first, but definitely worth a try!

Comment: your link asks for an authorization, I can't download  ;)

Comment: Sorry!!! Now it should work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you can do to convert it to a curve:

- Go in *Edit* mode, as it is triangulate, select all and untriangulate with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>:

[image]

- Also, you have ripped edges so <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to merge by distance:

[image]

- Select an edge loop, separate with <kbd>P</kbd>:

[image]

- Go into the *Object* menu to convert the mesh to curve:

[image]

- To simplify the curve, you can enable the *Simplify Curves* addon, then in *Edit* mode press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Curve Simplify*, in the *Operator* box choose an *Error* value of 1 and *Output > Bezier*, it's going to create a simplified version of your curve:

[image]

- Press <kbd>V</kbd> if you ever want to switch from *Automatic* handles to *Aligned*:

[image]

- Now you can do whatever you want with this curve:

[image]

Comment: That solution is perfect and exactly what I hoped to for! Honestly, I can't thank you enough :)

Comment: Hello @Verena :). You can thank moonboots by **upvoting** and **accepting ✓** the answer.